# The 'posts edited' counter can be inaccurate? in the very specific case of multiple edits to the same CW post. Bug or intended?

Tags: bug, edits, community-wiki

Recently I edited a Community Wiki post to add an alternate solution (a fairly major edit). Then I noticed that I'd misspelled the other contributor's name, so I edited it again to fix this error (a very minor edit). It was a surprise to see that this showed up as two separate posts edited on my profile page stats!

Before, it said "2 posts edited".

Now, it says "4 posts edited" — would have expected it to be "3"

I don't know whether this is due to a bug (it should have only counted as 1 new post edited because both edits were to the same post) or is intended functionality (because there isn't a reliable method of differentiating major and minor CW edits as there's no review process). My question is really whether editing the *same* post twice should count the same as editing two *different* posts, because at least in this case, it did.

Comment: Looks like a bug - it does not bump the stat for every normal revision one makes.